# React Relay passing data from parent to this.props.children

Tags: reactjs, relayjs, relay, relaymodern

I have a parent component that requests data from the root like so:

```
export default createFragmentContainer(App, {
  viewer: graphql`
    fragment App_viewer on User {
      id
      email
      name
    }
  `
})
```

Because I'm using React Router, the child routes are available through this component's `this.props.children`. I'd like to pass the `email` and `name` of the viewer to this child by setting data requirements through fragments.

I was doing something like this:

```
const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(
  this.props.children, (child) => React.cloneElement(child, {viewer})
);
```

But that's really over-generalized for cases where all `viewer` data is not necessary. Is there a simple way to have the child declare its data needs? Thanks!

Comment: What prevents you from making each child a fragment container also ?

Comment: Hi @whitep4nther, I am trying to make each child a fragment container also, that would be ideal. However, I want to share the same data between parent and child, can't seem to find a way to do it.

Comment: Do you know about Fragment spread ?

Comment: I do, that was a good suggestion. I didn't understand that what I should be doing is pulling the children data requirements out of the parent. There were 2 layers deep repeated data requirements and I need to flatten it into a single layer. I'll write an answer soon. Thanks @whitep4nther

Comment: Scratch that, that doesn't solve the problem. Because the child routes are nested, they don't get direct access to the apps primary query. Still stuck...

Comment: Can you upload your code online ? Like on github or something. I'm still having a hard time figuring the big picture lol